# Get only table columns with DbConnection.GetSchema method

Tags: sql-server-2005, getschematable

With C# and SQL Server 2005 and by using `DbConnection.GetSchema()` method, I want to get all a table's columns (not of views) only. I have found two collection names related to this

1. `Columns`  that returns table and views' columns
2. `ViewColumns` returns all the view's columns

Neither of above two returns table columns only, nor they have any property to filter Table-columns.

Any help is respected.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any easy way to do this with this particular API you're trying to achieve this with - but why not just use a query like this to get your information?

```
SELECT
    c.name AS 'ColumName',
    ty.Name AS 'TypeName',
    c.max_length,
    c.is_identity,
    c.is_nullable,
    t.name AS 'TableName'
FROM sys.columns c
INNER JOIN sys.types ty ON c.user_type_id = ty.user_type_id
INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
```

Just load that into a `SqlCommand` and execute it against the open connection you have and read the result into some `DataTable` or other structure for your use. This gives you **only** table columns - and all of them.

Comment: I know we can achieve this in your way, But I am doing all other operations with this method like 1)Getting ForeignKeys with connection.GetSchema("ForeignKeys") 2) Getting Indexes with connection.GetSchema("INDEXES"), same as i want to Get all Table-Columns by this method

Comment: @user369182: as I said - I don't think there's any way to get that information you want the way you want.